# In FineUploader Plugin scale , how can i define the height and width not the full width (max width option)

Tags: fine-uploader

how can I set height and width in scaling and can I depend on the image generated  (quality and professional scale generation).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Show your code / effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I set height and width in scaling

You can't. Specify a `maxSize` for each [`scaling.sizes` entry](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#scaling.sizes) and Fine Uploader will proportionally scale the image.

> can I depend on the image generated (quality

Quality will be limited if you rely on the browser only. There is an [entire section in the documentation that explains how you can generate higher-quality resizes by integrating a third-party resize library](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/scaling.html#using-a-third-party-library-to-resize-images). I also discuss why you may or may not want to do this. From the documentation:

> Fine Uploader's internal image resize code delegates to the drawImage
>   method on the browser's native CanvasRenderingContext2D object. This
>   object is used to manipulate a  element, which represents a
>   submitted image File or Blob. Most browsers use linear interpolation
>   when resizing images. This can lead to extreme aliasing and moire
>   patterns which is a deal breaker for anyone resizing images for
>   art/photo galleries, albums, etc. These kinds of artifacts are
>   impossible to remove after the fact.
>
> If speed is most important, and precise scaled image generation is not
>   paramount, you should continue to use Fine Uploader's internal scaling
>   implementation. However, if you want to generate higher quality scaled
>   images for upload, you should instead use a third-party library to
>   resize submitted image files, such as pica or limby-resize. As of
>   version 5.10 of Fine Uploader, it is extremely easy to integrate such
>   a plug-in into this library. In fact, Fine Uploader will continue to
>   properly orient the submitted image file and then pass a properly
>   sized  to the image scaling library of your choice to receive
>   the resized image file, along with the original full-sized image file
>   drawn onto a  for reference. The only caveat is that, due to
>   issues with scaling larger images in iOS, you may need to continue to
>   use Fine Uploader's internal scaling algorithm for that particular OS,
>   as other third-party scaling libraries most likely do not contain
>   logic to handle this complex case. Luckily, that is easy to account
>   for as well.
>
> If you'd like to, for example, use pica to generate higher-quality
>   scaled images, simply pull pica into your project, and contribute a
>   scaling.customResizer function, like so:
>
> ```
> scaling: {
>     customResizer: !qq.ios() && function(resizeInfo) {
>         return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
>             pica.resizeCanvas(resizeInfo.sourceCanvas, resizeInfo.targetCanvas, {}, resolve)
>         })
>     },
>     ...
> }
> ```

Comment: in the future , as an update the height and width will be existed as an parameters we can use ?

Comment: Just wondering if there was any update on the best way to specify a seperate Max Width and Max Height?